# Rails file upload: upload a folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip, carrierwave

I work on Rails project and client asked if I can add 'upload a folder' feature to simple file upload system that we have now. Currently it attaches files to model and then displays them on a page for download. Pretty basic.

But I can't figure out how can I handle folder uploads, with every folder having it's own content. Is there any pre-made gems that can help accomplish that?

We use Paperclip at the moment, but I don't mind migrating to Carrerwave or some other gem that would

**UPDATE** I see that I was unclear about my needs. I need an upload system that could handle folders. Something like this.
[image]
In Dropbox I am able to upload both files and folders. How can I make my uploaders accept folders and then display them alongside regular attached files?

Comment: What you acully needs ?

Comment: If you are using the paperclip then it use the record id as folder name and then push the file inside it.

Comment: Share your configuration inside the model of paperclip.

Comment: @Bharatsoni Please take a look at question update

Comment: These links might help you: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/demos/upload_directory/index.html and http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by using the interpolation of paperclip where you can create or naming the folder dynamically for the same you need to do like below

specify the path into model which you wanted always

```
   :path => ":folder/:id_:filename"
```

and specify the private method in same model or using globally specify in initializer

```
Paperclip::interpolates :folder do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.name
end
```